# How to check if a field is updated when inserting from table to table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data inserted from TableA to TableB. I'm inserting the data from TableA to TableB using a query that automatically runs every 4 hours. The query contains a insert, update and a delete.

> Date_***_*__*_*_***Group*  ____*State*  ___*BeginTime*  ___*EndTime
>
>   2012-11-1* _*A*  __*_*__*_*__*1*     __*_*____*08:00*   __*_*____16:00

The application that uses TableB can also change the field State but I need to check if this is changed by the application. There is no any attribute how I can check this.

I tried to create a new column 'FromTableA' (bit) into TableB to hold a state that means, this data coming from TableA. But when the application changes the state, the attribute FromTableA stays TRUE so I can't check this.

Any ideas to solve the problem, using just a query? Changes in the application are not allowed.

Comment: SQL server 2008, but I think the solution need to work on SQL server 2005 also.

Comment: If application update state you need change state on 1 if not then 0.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is a combination of separate timestamps fields - one that you will update in your automated query and a trigger that will update another timestampt of last update on the table. Compare the two, if they are not equal -> the fields where updated somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have an example? I never did this before.

Comment: Create two timestamp fields (`recordUpdatedOn` and `batchUpdatedOn`) in the table. Update `batchUpdatedOn` in your batch SQL.  
Create an `ON UPDATE` trigger (read SQL docs how to do it) to update `recordUpdatedOn` field when the trigger fires.  
If you only do `INSERT` in your batch (NOT `UPDATE`) than you can get away with only one field `recordUpdatedOn`, just make sure that you make the field NULL-able and insert NULL into it in your batch SQL.